# how to install reptyr on Mac?

Tags: macos, process, multiprocessing

I have found this very useful package that can transfer one process to another terminal. It is called Reptyr and there is a good manual on how to install it on other [OS](https://www.ostechnix.com/reptyr-move-running-process-new-terminal/) but not macOS. I did try brew but it was not available. Is there another way to install it on MacOS?

Comment: Maybe try `tmux` or GNU `screen`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few issues raised on GitHub regarding mac support

1. https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr/issues/99
2. https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr/issues/83

The bottom line is that this awesome tool cannot be installed on mac.

https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr/issues/83#issuecomment-296238492

> "nelhage commented on Apr 21, 2017
>
> We don't support macOS, unfortunately. Probably that should be a better error, though, at least …"
>   and it looks like it is not going to be supported.